# Python - How to get display card memory on Windows

Tags: python, directx

`Dxdiag` has very useful data about display card information, but I couldn't find any command line to get silent output from it. I need to get the memory of user's graphic card on Windows. Is there any solution to get it via `Dxdiag` or other resources?

I am using Python 2.7 on Windows 8.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dxdiag has the following command line options that could output information sliently,

> ```
> /x outfile    Silently save XML information to <outfile> and quit. 
>
> /t outfile    Silently save txt information to <outfile> and quit.
> ```

So, you can simply use "dxdiag /x myoutputfile" or "dxdiag /t myoutputfile"

Comment: Thanks. I did it then I opened XML file into my project. The problem was the `outfile` path, because it couldn't accept space character, so I changed the current dir of python using `chdir()` to temp folder, then I made a bat file and wrote that command line with dxdiag. then I ran the bat file using `subprocess` and after creation of XML file, I loaded it into my project.

Comment: How do you read the results from Python? I tried using `subprocess.check_output`, but it doesn't wait for the command to complete. It seems that dxdiag detaches itself from the parent process.

Answer (score 1):

Dxdiag takes quite a while to complete (15 seconds on my setup), so it's probably not ideal to use from within code. 
Consider using:

```
  wmic path win32_VideoController get AdapterRam
```

That might be the information you are looking for. Additionally, you may be able to get extra information from the wmic interface.